# Can Magic SysRq be used to switch workstations or kill specific processes?

Tags: process, sysrq

My PC, running Ubuntu from a live CD, is frozen. I think it's because I have too many Firefox tabs open, which is overloading my memory. Is there anyway to use Magic SysRq to only kill Firefox? Or to switch workstations or something to try and restore functionality?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and running `killall firefox`?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't work. Should I use a Magic SysRq to regain keyboard access and then try Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Answer (score 2):

No. The nearest thing you can do is use `Alt + SysRQ + K` which should kill all processes in current VT (in this case it should mean firefox, all graphical programs you were running, your WM and X itself). Then you should be able to switch to another console (using `Ctrl + Alt + F[1-6]` and run another instance of X from there (I don't use Ubuntu, but I'd bet there is a `startx` script for that).

SysRQ enables you to do only very "violent" and massive things: shutdown immediately (`o`), reboot immediately (`b`), kill everything except init (`i`), remount all filesystems as readonly (`u`) ... You probably see that a single letter is not enough to convey the "killall -9 firefox" command.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then SysRq won't be much use to me because the whole point of this is to recover unsaved files that are still open.

Comment: You're welcome. If you cannot switch VTs using `Ctrl + Alt + F[1-6]`, then I'm afraid I cannot help you. I have no experience with Live CDs and this issue seems to be connected just with liveCDness of your system :(