# how to recover from a freeze without rebooting?

Tags: command-line, freeze, system, virtual-console, sysrq

What alternatives are there to `REISUB` for [dealing with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) system problems?  The windows task manager has its good points in this regard.  Or, key combination to logout.  It's not always possible to get to a virtual console.

Some combination to just logout would be my preference.  Or kill the window system and revert to CLI.  [Anything](https://askubuntu.com/a/511886/45156) but a reboot.

But how do you then recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Alt + sysreq + k
```

will effectively log you out by killing all processes on the current (virtual) console.